# Is this question asking for an Eclipse plugin off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons, off-topic

Is the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/21253155/1309352 off-topic on Stack Overflow?

And if so, why?

Comment: Why the 5 downvotes on this question? OP here is not the OP on SO, and he's in favour of closing the question.

Comment: @Stijn Meta is hard, unforgiving world ;) Be clear or suffer. (downvote retracted)

Comment: I'm guessing some confusion between "Hey it's closed and it states why" and the timing of this happening @Stijn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Also, they tend to be primarily opinion based anyway, so 2 close reasons to choose from.

Either way, it's kind of a [shopping list question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), answers will tell user what to do, but they all be opinions that can't be honestly and objectively evaluated. If one plugin supports practice X, and other practice Y, then which one to choose? Second problem is time. Recommendations will cease to be valid pretty soon. Eclipse will update, half of the plugins will be unavailable, and answers recommending them will be useless.

Last but not least, questions like that (and answers to them) does not teach. They don't help anyone to be a better software developer - just like getting better hammer does not make you a better carpenter. It might help to get a bit better results, all right, but it's a short term only effect - sooner or alter another tool will be needed.